# Is it possible to pass a parameter to settings.gradle

Tags: gradle

I would like to add a command line parameter to completetly skip some subprojects for performance reasons. My settings.gradle looks like this:

```
rootProject.name='MyProject'

if (!rootProject.hasProperty('NO_LIBRARY_BUILD')) {
    print "=== BUILDING OF LIBRARY PROJECTS. Pass -PNO_LIBRARY_BUILD to gradle to skip building ==="
    include('Lib1')
    project(':Lib1').projectDir=file('Path/to/Lib1')
    include('Lib2')
    project(':Lib2').projectDir=file('Path/to/Lib2')
}
else { 
    print "=== SKIPPING BUILD OF LIBRARY PROJECTS ==="
}
```

However, this does not work - passing -PNO_LIBRARY_BUILD still enters the "building" part of the if. I assume that these properties are not passed to rootProject, but somewhere else.
How can I access (more so, how can I check for the existence of) the NO_LIBRARY_BUILD command line parameter from the settings gradle?

Answer (score 1):

I found that what worked was using simply 
hasProperty('NO_BUILD_LIBRARIES') without specifying the project.

Comment: It still works for me for an upgraded gradle version up to this date. It is plausible that it might not work for earlier versions, but I can confirm it still works until today.

Comment: Tested on Gradle 7.1.1. Just using hasProperty does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Gradle 7.1.1. Just using hasProperty does not work. Using settings.hasProperty('abc') works with -Pabc=true.
Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html